# Storing Dynamic Input into a PHP Variable

Tags: php, html

I have a bunch of check boxes, one of them being "Other". Once the user checks other, it opens up a new input field for more details. I need to store the input value in a PHP variable using POST. Below is what I have but I can't seem to find more information on how to do this since it's a little more specific.

**HTML:**

```html
        <td>Categories?</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="P">Poster<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="B">Brochure<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="F">Flyer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="M">Mailer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="N">Newsletter<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="G">Program<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="V">Invitations<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="O" onclick="dynInput(this);">Other<br>
    <p id="insertinputs"></p>
</td>
```

**Js:**

```js
 function dynInput(cbox) {
  if (cbox.checked) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = cbox.name;
    div.innerHTML = "Explain: ";
    div.appendChild(input);
    document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div);
  } else {
    document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting it, do you want to submit your form to some .php file? or just wants to show the Selections at in the same web page using javascript ? Or you want to show dynamic HTML in the same manner?

Comment: Rather than adding the input dynamically, why not add it to the HTML, using Javascript to show it when the user selects Other? 

You can also use js to hide it when loading the form, thus having a failover if javascript is disabled for some reason.

Comment: I am trying to submit it to some .php file using $_POST @hmd

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. The problem isn't with Js here, I just need to store the value in a PHP variable using $_POST @bjelleklang

Comment: Dude why don't you use JQuery? Can I write some JQuery in solution?

Comment: What input value are you referring when you say: **"I need to store the input value in a PHP variable"** ? Is the "Other" input or those checkboxes  inputs?... or both?

Comment: Actually, the problem is the js. My js is too rusty to add a solution, but if the textbox is added the value you write into it should be submitted to the PHP backend as a normal post-request. If it doesn't exist in the html, nothing is submitted regardless of what PHP does.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to create a field, give it a name then hide it and every time user click on other show it, then when you submit your form the field will be sent as post just like `categories[]` but with given name (in my example `other_category`) :

**JS :**

```
function dynInput(cbox) {
    if (cbox.checked) {
      document.getElementById("other").className="";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("other").className="hidden";
    }
}
```

**CSS :** (Used just to avoid inline style)

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="P">Poster<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="B">Brochure<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="F">Flyer<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="M">Mailer<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="N">Newsletter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="G">Program<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="V">Invitations<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="O" onclick="dynInput(this);">Other<br>
<div class="hidden" id="other">
  Explain: <input type="text" name="other_category"/>
</div>
```

**PHP :** (After submit)

```
 $_POST["other_category"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think he needs to modify the JS, you can check the existence of the variable "other_category" and perform the same task.

<?php if (isset($_POST['other_category']) ... etc, etc

Comment: Thanks but I am in need of the PHP snippet, not the Js or HTML @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: @RicardoVigatti i think he need because of extra code and bad implementation, i'm offer hem simple code do the same think he want in proper way..

Comment: @Gela all you want is `$_POST["other_category"]`

Comment: Thank you, I figured out the PHP part and it's all working now thanks to your revised Js @Zakaria Acharki

Answer (score 1):

Don't bite me if I'm wrong but if you are looking to dynamically show an extra form when the user ticks the options, perhaps you can have it like

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="V">Invitations<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="O" onclick="dynInput(this);">Other<br>
    <input type="text" id="others" style="display: none;" name="other" placeholder="Please specify"></input>
    <p id="insertinputs"></p>
```

and with the JS,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dynInput(cbox) {
    if (cbox.checked) {
        document.getElementById("others").style.display = "initial";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("others").style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

then, you can handle the extra `$_POST['others']` server-side!

Comment: There is no need to change the javascript, since you can check the existence of the variable on the PHP. Use isset($_POST['other']) and assign a default value if needed.

Comment: Yes, that's true but my javascript edit does not validate the existence of the variable, only dynamically shows/hides the extra text input if or if not the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have Created a Code using Jquery. it may be help for you.

```
<script>
    $("#dynInput").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).prop( "checked" ))
        $('#insertinputs').html('<input type="text" name="FieldName" >');
        else
            $('#insertinputs').html('');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP solution, don't need to modify the JS:

```
<?php
    $categories = $_POST['categories'];

    // check the existence of the "other_field" variable,
    // if it not exists, assign a default value (an empty string in our case).
    $other_field = isset($_POST['other_field']) ? $_POST['other_field'] : '';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP didn't tagged [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) in the question. But I'm giving some JQuery solution it may help the OP or someone else.

**HTML:**

```
<!--Including JQUERY library through google api-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form type="POST" action="yourfile.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Categories?</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="P">Poster<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="B">Brochure<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="F">Flyer<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="M">Mailer<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="N">Newsletter<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="G">Program<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="V">Invitations<br>
                <input class="other_category" type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="O">Other<br>
                <p id="insertinputs" style="display:none;">
                    <input type="text" name="categories[other]" value="">
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Javascipt/JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // On click event for Other Checkbox 'other_category' by using '#' selector
    $( "#other_category" ).click(function() {

        // Checking if Other Checkbox is checked or not
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            // Showing 'insertinputs' div
            $("#insertinputs").show();
        }else{
            // So, if the clicked checkbox isn't 'Other' we are hiding the div
            $("#insertinputs").hide();
        }

        // making input field value empty on click of Other checkbox
        $("#insertinputs input").val('');

    });
});

</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// yourfile.php
if( !empty($_POST['categories']) ){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['categories']);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  list($var1, $var2) = explode(' ', readline());
  
  // Typecasting to integers
  $var1 = (int)$var1;
  $var2 = (int)$var2;
  
  echo "The sum of " . $var1 . " and "
    . $var2 . " is " . ($var1 + $var2);
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.